# Using ag-grid for tabular display

Tags: dashboard, ag-grid, node-red

I want to use [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/) to display incoming data as a table and also provide an option to export as CSV. I used the reference from [here](http://noderedguide.com/tutorial-node-red-dashboards-creating-your-own-ui-widget-ii-using-external-charts/) and [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/) to insert code into the template node.

This is my template code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.noStyle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 600px;width:500px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
<script>
    (funtion(scope) {
        var columnDefs = [
            {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
            {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
            {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
        ];
        //
        var rowData = [
            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
            {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
        ];
        //
        var gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            rowData: rowData
        };
        //
        var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        var testGrid = new agGrid.Grid(gridOptions);
        //
        scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
                    if (msg) {
                        row = [
                            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000}
                        ];
                        testGrid.setRowData(row);
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )(scope);
</script>
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at m (app.min.js:20)
    at Re (app.min.js:20)
    at w.fn.init.append (app.min.js:20)
    at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (app.min.js:20)
    at z (app.min.js:20)
    at w.fn.init.html (app.min.js:20)
    at app.min.js:565
    at m.$digest (app.min.js:165)
    at m.$apply (app.min.js:168)
    at app.min.js:181
```

How do I get past this error and show MQTT payload as a table?

Comment: can you try not minify the js when packaging the app so one can see on which line the error is?

Comment: Sorry, no. My only interface here is the template node in node rec dashboard.

Comment: unpkg.com probably hosts a none minified version which you could point to instead

Comment: Thank you, Ben, for your consistent support with Node-RED! I was hoping some one from ag-grid would respond; following up on GitHub.

Comment: I located the non-minified version (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ag-grid) but, I still see the same error from `app.min.js`.